# Selenium context click(right click) menu disappears(in a second) in firefox version 86 on browserstack

Tags: selenium, contextmenu

Performing automation using python selenium. I have page on which I perform **right click** and proceed with the options on the right click menu. But on **firefox version 86** I see that the right click disappears within a second. Is this any version specific bug? Meanwhile I am trying on the other versions to rule out if it's related to this version. Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have some code to share? What are you trying to do with the context menu?

Comment: We have page where we perform right click and obtain menu options and click on one of the options and  **proceed. actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.context_click(on_element=element).perform()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to `pass sleep in Action chains.`

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).context_click().pause(5).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey. The solution with pause and along with some retry mechanism helped.